# Stop CSS overriding HTML width attribute

Tags: html, css

I have some old content containing tables with their width specified with an HTML width attribute like so: `<table width="250">`. This attribute is being overridden by a rule for the CSS selector `table`. Can I stop this overriding so the tables have the width specified in the HTML attributute (which is not always 250 pixels, this is just an example)? I can pick out the tables which shouldn't have their widths overridden with the selector `#column1 table`.

Comment: why can't you simply remove the css `width` rule that overrides the attribute?

Comment: Because this is on a _lot_ of old imported content. I could possibly write a find-replace script which did that for all tables that match #column1 table but it'd be good to find a simpler way.

Comment: I suppose it would be better remove all inline width and height attributes, otherwise you will have to likely add other inline styles, as suggested by Christopher Kenney

Comment: I see, you imported the html, right? You could try (I am not sure if it works) to add !important to your CSS styles. You use it like this: table {width: 250px !important;}

Comment: As far as I understood, 250px is only an example width, right @tog22 ? or all tables are 250px large?

Comment: Yes, someone imported it. Alas, 250 pixels is just an example - the width differs.

Comment: Fabrizio, you're right. To more clearly answer your initial comment, this is a complex site I've inherited and I believe the rule for the CSS selector table is important for other parts of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
#column1 table {
    width: auto;
}
```

Just so you know, css will always override old html inline attributes. This is usually a problem when using a wysiwyg editor.

I solved this problem for the old html generated by a wysiwyg editor in a cms with javascript and jquery. I iterate over the table(s) and read the width and height attribute which I then convert to inline css:

```
var $table = $('#column1 table');
$table.css({
    "width" : $table.attr('width'),
    "height" : $table.attr('height')
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I have tried it. It calculates the table's with as if there were no CSS or HTML width attribute applied to it.

Comment: Just use width: 250px instead of auto.

Comment: @tog22 I've added the javascript (and jquery) solution I once used.

Comment: why are you going for such a difficult solution when no js is needed, just plain and simple CSS? This would make the whole code even more dirty!

Comment: The js solution I posted was for the case of a wysiwyg editor being used. Using !important can cause other issues which I'm not willing to face.

Comment: Accepted because this bit of jquery's the only answer that'd solve my precise situation, much as I appreciate the difficulties with it, and also appreciate the other answers (in particular the suggestion of a mass find and replace).

Answer (score 6):

I know this question was asked 2 years ago, but it might be helpful for others who have similar issues. You can use CSS attribute selector:

```
table:not([width]) {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Note that it won't work under IE 9 as far as i know.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question does it?

Comment: Thanks for this - I ended up using `table[width=''] {` to also catch elements where the attribute was present but not set to anything (eg. `<table width>`)

Answer (score 5):

you can't override the css with html but you can add the attribute `style`
for example:

```
style = " width: 250px;"
```

edit: You can override it externally by putting !important on the end of the css rule which will cancel out any other css attributes in relation to what you're changing.

eg:

```
#column1 table {
  width: 250px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but see my clarifying comment on the original question.

Comment: @togg22: yes, the !important could help. However, I would not use it as style="..." but rather in a stylesheet. Otherwise you could do a find-replace, which would be recommended anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell us why you are using inline html attributes like this?

Unless you have a very strong reason, I advise you to move any style-related things to CSS. And it is much better if the CSS has its own file, not included inline as well.

It is a better practice to always separate content from presentation.

Comment: I know, see my clarifying comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

A possible though inelegant answer that's occurred to me is to replace the rule for the CSS selector `table` with one for `:not(#column1) table`. However this'll only work in some modern browsers and not IE.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, I would suggest you to use a stylesheet for that! You just implement this into your styles.css:

```
table {
   width:250px;
}
```

and if not enough, you can add !important, like:

```
table {
   width:250px !important;
}
```

And add the stylesheet like this in the head part of your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stlyes.css">
```

Otherwise you would need to add the style="width:250px" directly to each table. If you then want to change the width again to e.g. 260px, you would have to change all of them again.

However, if you have access to your HTML code, doing a Find-Replace would be recommended, anyway to have a clean code. Almost any even very simple TextEdit Programm should have a Find-Replace option...

Answer (score -2):

Take a look this link.. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

In the html put Id  i.e.

> 

on the table and then in the css just do

```
#TABLE1
{
width:250;
}
```