# Override images from getting height+width from CSS, html attribute instead

Tags: html, css, image, height

I have a universal style applied to avatars, but in this situation I want to override that to get height and width from the html attributes.

```
   <img src="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/4/21b534c3f0db3355775089689cb4e003-bpthumb.jpg" class="avatar user-4-avatar avatar-14 photo" width="14" height="14" alt="Avatar of user">

img.avatar {
   height: 80px;
   width: 80px;
 }


.bbpress img.avatar, .forum img.avatar {
   /*what rule do I put here to make the avatar use the html attribute for sizing?*/
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
 }
```

I don't want to change any html, just CSS... is there any way to do this? I tried `auto`, but that makes it its natural height and width.

Comment: Please add your html.

Comment: Not to be an absolutist, but I'd suggest avoiding HTML attributes, styles should be in your stylesheet, not your semantic HTML document. Also, once you start applying CSS styles, they can't be overriden by HTML styling elements.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no means for doing this in CSS, as the width/height/border/etc attributes in markup are always going to be overridden by CSS properties of the same type. The only way you could do this, really, would be through Javascript, to set the CSS styles based on the attribute values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770818/stop-css-overriding-html-width-attribute

Comment: As a second aside, be careful about re-sizing images using CSS... browsers typically do a poor job of it.

Comment: check you css/html can't see why what have done does not work. Use an inspector to check whats being inherited by what. Does it work if you change auto to a pixel width?

Comment: @ChrisHardie I agree. I'm using a wordpress plugin and I'm not interested in rewriting all of their templates ;)

Comment: @matpol I can set a specific pixel width, but I want to not have to in case I haven't accounted for every size variation in someone else's template.  Although as mentioned it may not be possible with CSS

Comment: set the size of a div wrapper around and set the width/height of the image to be 100%. This is not ideal as images will be stretched and squashed. There will always be caveats with what you are trying to do though

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *entirely* sure what you're asking or what you mean by get the width and height from html attributes.

The only thing I can share is that using auto you get the initial width and height, determined by your browser

Or you can use `!important` after each css attribute to make sure it overrides everything.

Or by using css inline with `style="width:##;height:##"` that will override the CSS sheet (but not !important attributes).

I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: I realized my img tag didn't get encoded properly so it wasn't showing up.. edited so the problem should be more clear now