# CSS, how to size an img back to its width attribute

Tags: css, image, attributes

I've got an imagereference in the markup with attributes width and height.

```
<img src="//example.com/img.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
```

This is styled with:

```
img {
width: 100%;
}
```

How can I get back to its *"pseudo initial value"* using CSS without changing the markup or knowing the exact value of its dimensions.

I tried to use *width: auto;* but it shows the actual dimensions of the image not the one set by the attributes.

I know that those are also kinda CSS. But is there a way to do this in CSS?
[There is also a codepen sample I you could play around with here:](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrFml)  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrFml

Hopefully it is clear what I want to do. :-)

Well thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting a style that you want to undo? (I'm intrigued by the potential answers, but it seems to be something of a self-created problem.)

Comment: You could set `max-width: 200px;`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Is the native resolution 200 x 200 or is it set to 200 x 200 in the HTML but its actually a different size? Either way you should just remove the height and width attrib from your HTML and do it all with CSS

Comment: @DavidThomas you are kinda right that it is a self-created problem.
Therefore I could use the :not pseudoclass in the normalize.css

But the way it is now is HTML Attributes are set via Backend. 
In most cases these are correct (display dimensions not pixels of the images). But the layout is crazy. Images are  resized all over the place. 
I want to know if it is possible to get them back to those attributes no matter what I do before.

Comment: Unfortunatly unset and initial are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same Problem without a solution:
[Override images from getting height+width from CSS, html attribute instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520498/override-images-from-getting-heightwidth-from-css-html-attribute-instead)

and a similar one:
[Stop CSS overriding HTML width attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770818/stop-css-overriding-html-width-attribute)

So I'll guess the only way to get this done is not to overwrite the ones you want to get back to using :not().

Answer (score 0):

first remove the img rule of your sheet.
if you want to use **dom attrs** lets work with **dom attrs**, you should use inline styles to achieve this.

use javascript to set this inline rule:

```
width: 100%;
```

and then use js again to overwrite it as:

```
width: inherit;
```

this makes the element cascade back again to the 'width' attribute of its html

Comment: Inherit will not necessarily revert back to using the `width` attribute of the image but whatever is the next closing CSS selector that targets the image width, then if none exist, the width attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, there is a keyword [`revert-layer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert-layer) which reverts the value back to its previous cascade-layer, which in most cases is the user-agent. As the browser's user-agent applies extrinsic `width`, `height` and `aspect-ratio` to the image based on its size attributes, `revert-layer` reverts back to exactly that.

However, the catch is that it's appearantly not supported on browsers other than Firefox... according to the [support table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert-layer#browser_compatibility). Although it still works in recent Chromium-based browsers I've tried as of today. If in doubt, there's `@supports` too.

Answer (score -3):

You can't change a HTML-style with CSS.

Comment: Thats not true.
width & height html attributes are also CSS in a way. You can overwrite them with an unspecific selector. 
You can also overwrite style attributes with important. :-)