# Reset css img width to old width property value

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a framework where a global css rule

```
img {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

is set - that I cannot change. Now I'm working with a WYSIWYG editor that resizes images by setting their (old) `width` property. Is there any chance to reset it to the element's size via css?

e.g.

```
.container img {
    width: unset; // (or initial)
}
```

But that obviously doesn't work. Element inspector tells me

```
initial
removed: 100%
removed: 100px (value of the width property)
```

Here is a Stackblitz showing the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-rjtfrt?file=styles.css

I want the images' width to be 200 by just changing `.container img`.

Comment: You can override the property value using !important

Comment: What do you mean by 'old' width property?

Comment: Added an example - sorry, should have done this sooner.

Answer (score 0):

`Initial` or `fit-content` are values your are looking for. Depends if you want to set real image size or width attribute value.

Check two examples below.

```css
img {width: 100%;}
.container #img1 {width: initial;} /* taking real image width (300px) */
.container #img2 {width: fit-content;} /* taking width attribute value (200px) */
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <img id="img1" width=200 height=200 src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  <img id="img2" width=200 height=200 src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
</div>
```

A brief about browser support at https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content

Comment: Sorry, the question was a bit unclear - I added an example.

Comment: @tris: I think I gave you a solution. Check code snippet here. First image has 300px width (real image size), the second one 200px (attribute `width`). Why do you think it isn't what you asked?

Comment: It somehow isn't working for me - check my stackblitz.

Comment: @tris: Hmm, it works correctly in Mac/Safari, in Mac/Chrome doesn't... My fault, sorry.

Comment: How I love that we still haven't left these browser dependent struggles  But that you for checking! So I guess there _is_ no solution?

*Super* hacky: it works for width-style (but not property) when setting a broken value ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-rjtfrt?file=styles.css

But I guess so there *is* no solution? Really?

Comment: @tris In pure CSS I have no idea... your 'solution' is very tricky, I don't think it'd work in all browsers (IMHO if you set invalid value, than the last valid should be used - and it's 100%). Maybe someone else find any solution, I don't see it.. Sorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just found this questions: [CSS, how to size an img back to its width attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487919/css-how-to-size-an-img-back-to-its-width-attribute) and it really seams like there **is** no solution. Please correct me if I'm wrong!